# How to get sample data from sales force developer account through rest api

Tags: rest, api, web-services, salesforce

I need to get sample data from sales force developer account but i am unable to find any API to get any data from sales force.
Is there any API exposed by sales force to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce exposes a large number of thoroughly documented APIs.

Access to record data is most commonly achieved through the standard [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm).

You may be most interested in the endpoints named under [Working with Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_records.htm), which provide access to record data, or [Working with Searches and Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_working_with_searches_and_queries.htm).